# Timing of saying "Adonai sefatai tiftach" at beginning of Amidah

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

When does one say the 6 words starting with Adonai sefatai tiftach? Does one say it before taking three steps back, during taking the three steps back, after taking the three steps back but before walking forward, during walking forward, after walking forward?

Comment: Hey @eliyahu12, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your interesting question! I've added a tag to your question, to make it easier for people who know what they're talking about to find your question. Hope to see you around the site!

Answer (score 0):

From the Sefer Ishei Yisreol perek 23:13,14 on pg 228 it seems the proper action is to take three steps back(if thats your minhag(The Steipler did not) then take three steps forward and then say this phrase before saying shmoneh esrei. The phrase is considered a part of shmoneh esrei and not just an introduction( see Levush siman 111:1, and [Igros Moshe Chelek 5:24:8](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=922#) where he goes through a long discussion about this phrase and the importance of it.)